# What is the proper way of Exception Handling in the following scenario:

Tags: java, android, exception

I have an Async task which checks for user session. This task is responsible for contacting the server using a method - both are listed below:

```
public class SessionChecker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent intent;
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception")) {
            //We got an exception in URL Connection - letus restart the task -- this is recursive
            new SessionChecker().execute();
        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("server error")) {
            //We got an exception in URL Connection - letus restart the task -- this is recursive
            new SessionChecker().execute();
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(result)) {

                    String message = jObj.getString("message");

                    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("failure")) {
                        intent = new Intent(AppInitializer.this, AppWebViewLogin.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        intent = new Intent(AppInitializer.this, NavigationMasterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                //Malformed JSON - letus restart the task -- this is recursive
                new SessionChecker().execute();
            }
        }

    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            DomainManager domainManager = new DomainManager(AppInitializer.this);

            return UniversalNetworkConnection.simplePost(domainManager.getDomain() + getResources().getString(R.string.url_check_session));

        }
    }
```

Here is my URL Connection method:

```
public static String simplePost(String myurl) {
        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");

            sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory NoSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(NoSSLv3Factory);


            StringBuffer response;
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // conn.setReadTimeout(90000);
            // conn.setConnectTimeout(900000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(new URL(myurl).getHost());

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);


            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            switch (responseCode) {
                case 200:
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    return response.toString();
                default:
                    return "server error";
            }
        } catch (IOException | java.security.KeyManagementException | java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return "exception";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried handling the exceptions recursively - an exception occurs - The async task is reloaded, how can I improve this, I am not sure if the way I am doing this is the best practice? Any hints / solutions / tips would be really helpful.

Comment: Not, sure abut what is your application scenario, but restarting the async task again to get data again, when exception is thrown looks fine to me.

Comment: I am only afraid of this falling into an infinite loop..

Comment: Right, check out how the api works, in what condition it fails. Let's say if net is not on, you can check the internet state and then when it's on, you can restart your async task. Make sure, in what scenarios, you are going to make request.

Comment: Use variable to limit the number of retry that is acceptable for you

Comment: In my case I try to get data at least 6 times

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, but also check for net connectivity before retrying.

Comment: Valid points, I am going to introduce a retry count mechanism.